# Remove htaccess rules from root to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

In a forum within a subfolder (called 'forum') the Rewrite rules from Codeigniter (root folder) are affecting the forum subfolder.  Here are the root htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now if for example I try to access any URL for the forum, `/forum/index.php?action=removetopic2;topic=14.0;` the site will launch an error because of these rules. Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `RewriteCond` to stop a rule from matching `/forum`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/
```

See the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It seems that `%{REQUEST_URI}` includes the first slash behind the hostname if I read the documentation.